# When creating multiple environment variables references are not being expanded

Tags: vbscript

When creating multiple environment variables in sequence using VBS, the earlier variables are never getting expanded when referenced in the later variables.

```
Set wshUserEnv = objShell.Environment( "USER" )
wshUserEnv("A") = "a"
wshUserEnv("b") = "%A%\b"
```

Then,

```
objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(GetEnvVariable("b"))
```

does not give the value of a\b, but, instead stays as %A%\b

Also, listing the values from command line prints the same value. But, once the variable is edited (minor edit like adding a semicolon) from System Properties dialog, the variable gets expanded.

GetEnvVariable is a helper function:

```
Function GetEnvVariable (EnvVariable)
    Dim wshUserEnv
    Set wshUserEnv = objShell.Environment( "USER" )
    GetEnvVariable=wshUserEnv(EnvVariable)
End Function
```

Comment: What is `GetEnvVariable()` ?

Comment: It is a helper function which is in effect

Comment: `objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%b%")` gives me `a\b`, as expected. It's not clear how does `GetEnvVariable()` work, better you to share the whole code.

Comment: Displaying the value using MsgBox works. But, still in the command prompt the values are not getting expanded. I am specifically updating the PATH variable with this reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()` behavior:

Run the first script below:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' set values to variables
objShell.Environment("user")("user___var") = "user___value"
objShell.Environment("process")("process___var") = "process___value"
objShell.Environment("system")("system___var") = "system___value"
objShell.Environment("volatile")("volatile___var") = "volatile___value"

s = "check accessibility within running script process" & vbCrLf
s = s & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%user___var%") & vbCrLf
s = s & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%process___var%") & vbCrLf
s = s & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%system___var%") & vbCrLf
s = s & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%volatile___var%") & vbCrLf
WScript.Echo(s)

objShell.Run "cmd.exe /k echo check accessibility within child process & echo %user___var% & echo %process___var% & echo %system___var% & echo %volatile___var%"
```

The output will be the same for both `WScript.Echo` and `cmd.exe /k echo`:

```
%user___var%
process___value
%system___var%
%volatile___var%
```

After that run the second script:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

s = "check accessibility via another script process" & vbCrLf
s = s & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%user___var%") & vbCrLf
s = s & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%process___var%") & vbCrLf
s = s & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%system___var%") & vbCrLf
s = s & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%volatile___var%") & vbCrLf
WScript.Echo(s)

objShell.Run "cmd.exe /k echo check accessibility via another script process & echo %user___var% & echo %process___var% & echo %system___var% & echo %volatile___var%"
```

The output will be:

```
user___value
%process___var%
system___value
volatile___value
```

I've checked behavior on Win7 x64 and VirtualBox WinXP. As you can see, `process` environment is only accessible for `.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()` within running process or via child process, that first script shows. Other environments are not accessible for `.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()` until running script (in which variables were set) finishes. When you run second script, you become able to read all environments variables via `.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`, except process.

I hope this explanation will help to get your code to work.

The code you show `objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(GetEnvVariable("b"))` gives you `%A%\b` because `GetEnvVariable("b")` returns `%A%\b` (`.Environment()` method implemented in the function has access to `user` environment, and all others environments, but it doesn't process contained `%A%` as variable statement, as `.ExpandEnvironmentStrings()` does), and then `.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%A%\b")` returns the value without any changes (the method has no access to `A` variable in `user` environment till script termination).

Comment: Thank you for the explanantion @omegastripes. But, even if it is not expanded in the current process, if I use this set the PATH environment variable at user level, it should get expanded in a new command line process right? But, it is not getting expanded resulting in the programs in the folder represented by unexpanded PATH not being executable with just the program name

Comment: I understand the explanation and I could think of an alternate approach for the problem at hand. But, I thought the variable references are evaluated for every process. So, for e.g. if I set user variable A in a process and in the same process set user variable B with reference to A, when another process starts, at least in the new process the references should have been resolved. Still a little confused. Thank you very much for the explanation, which helped me to identify an alternate solution.